# How to make SQL mirroring endpoint on clustered SQL 2012 instance listen to all IPs?

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring, endpoint

I have a clustered SQL 2012 standard instance and I want to set up database mirroring. I also need to route the mirroring traffic through a separate NIC. We added the secondary IP to the SQL server cluster role as an "IP address" resource, on failover cluster side the secondary network is configured to allow "Cluster and client" traffic. I added SQL server dependency on the secondary IP and restarted the role, but the mirroring endpoint is still listening only on the primary interface (SQL network name resource) of the clustered role.

The listener was created by this command:

`CREATE ENDPOINT [endpointMirror] STATE=STARTED
    AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 7022, LISTENER_IP = ALL)
    FOR DATA_MIRRORING (ROLE = PARTNER, AUTHENTICATION = WINDOWS NEGOTIATE, ENCRYPTION = REQUIRED)`

but it is really listening only on the primary clustered IP of the instance (e.g. 10.1.1.208):

```
C:\>netstat -ano | find "7022"
  TCP    10.1.1.208:7022     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       12584
```

while on a non-clustered SQL server which also has 2 network interfaces I see the desired behaviour and the endpoint listens on all IPs:

```
C:\>netstat -ano | find "7022"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7022           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3836
```

Any ideas, how to configure the clustered instance endpoint to listen on all interfaces? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was on the right path with just one mistake. The secondary IP must be added as a dependency for Server Name cluster resource, not for the SQL Server itself. After restart of SQL service it started listening on both IPs for both TSQL and mirroring endpoints.